# MemoryError when trying to save image of fits file with WCS in astropy

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, astropy, fits

I'm trying to make an image file (.png) of a large (~5GB) fits file with the WCS on the x and y axis. See [here](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/visualization/wcsaxes/) as an example, and here is a MWE:

```
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = path/to/image/image.fits
hdu = fits.open(image, ignore_missing_end=True)[0]
wcs = WCS(hdu.header)

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.subplot(projection=wcs)
plt.imshow(hdu.data, origin='lower')
plt.grid(color='white', ls='solid')
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')

plt.savefig('figure.png')
```

This keeps giving me the error below, even thought I'm working on a node with at least 16GB of RAM. Does anyone know how to solve this, or how to downgrade the resolution of the image while preserving the WCS? Thanks!

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "map.py", line 30, in <module>
plt.savefig('figure.png')
File "/hpc/c/anaconda2-4.1.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 688, in savefig
    res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/hpc/c/anaconda2-4.1.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1565, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)

  ... 

  im = self.make_image(renderer.get_image_magnification())
  File "/hpc/c/anaconda2-4.1.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 624, in make_image
    transformed_viewLim)
  File "/hpc/c/anaconda2-4.1.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 238, in _get_unsampled_image
    x = (x * 255).astype(np.uint8)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Have you tried using APLpy? It's much more out-of-the-box plotting of FITS images than trying to use matplotlib directly.

Comment: Yes, I did try APLpy and had similar memory issues.

Comment: Have you tried lowering the resolution of the .png output file?

Comment: Yes, I lowered the dpi (to something very low as a test) and I still got the same error.